# How does opencv use cv2.UMat() to speed up?I want to use GPU to speed up opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I have installed CUDA.

I want to use GPU to speed up opencv.

Which methods or objects can be accelerated?

I'm using opencv3 and python3.

Answer (score 3):

Just by using Umats instead of mats, it'll call OpenCL functions when available. No need to call special functions, just pass an Umat.

See this https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6078